# Pulling empty commits

Tags: git

We use tagged empty commits (`git commit -m 'Building release 0.1234' --allow-empty`) to push against gitlab to trigger the Jenkins pipeline. When I execute a pull I do not get those empty commits. Only when I checkout a specific tag (i.e. `git pull 0.1234`).

Is that a configuration issue or why are empty commits not included when executing a `git pull`?

Comment: Are you familiar with [annotated tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)?